# Synchronising different of a database - django

Tags: database, django, postgresql, data-synchronization

I have made a django web app (postgresql backend) for internal use for one of my clients in New Zealand.
They have told me that they would also like it to be used by one of their branches in Malaysia (it will need to be connected to the same database). The problem is that apparently in Malaysia the internet is really unpredictable and there is a lot of downtime.

So here is the question, what would be the best way for keeping the Malaysian branch running when their internet is down and having their version of the database synchronised with the main database back here in NZ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to synchronize your data and schema across multiple (2 in your case) postgresql databases.

There are a variety of solutions to do that depending on exactly what you want to achieve.  This is a good place to start - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/high-availability.html

and the summary of the different solutions and each solution's pros and cons are listed here - 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/different-replication-solutions.html#HIGH-AVAILABILITY-MATRIX

Comment: Nothing off-the-shelf will be perfect with an unreliable connection though. You will either have to make the Malaysian end read-only when the connection is broken (simple) or handle re-synching the two databases when the connection comes back up (complex).